# Type 'className -> () -> className!' does not conform to protocol

Tags: protocols, swift

I'm messing around with Swift. I have a protocol defined as

```
protocol timerProtocol {
    func timerFired()
}
```

A class who holds a reference to the delegate

```
class Stopwatch: NSObject {
    var delegate: protocol <timerProtocol>

    init(delegate: protocol <timerProtocol> ) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

...
}
```

and a class that implements the protocol

```
class StopwatchesTableViewController: UITableViewController, timerProtocol {

    func timerFired() {
        println("timer");
    }

    let stopwatch = Stopwatch(delegate: self) // Error here

...
}
```

I get the error when declaring the stopwatch - "Type 'StopwatchesTableViewController -> () -> StopwatchesTableViewController!' does not conform to protocol 'timerProtocol'"

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: you cannot refer the `self` as instance _until_ the instance does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Change `var delegate: protocol <timerProtocol>`

To `var delegate: timerProtocol?`

Answer (score 1):

syntactically and logically that works for me like a charm:

```
protocol TimerProtocol {
    func timerFired()
}

class Stopwatch {
    var delegate: protocol <TimerProtocol>? = nil
    
    init() { }
    
    convenience init(delegate: protocol <TimerProtocol> ) {
        self.init()
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

}

class StopwatchesTableViewController: UITableViewController, TimerProtocol {
    
    @lazy var stopwatch: Stopwatch = Stopwatch()
    
    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        stopwatch.delegate = self
    }
    
    func timerFired() {
        println("timer");
    }

}
```

*NOTE: the protocols' names should start with capital letter.*

## or

the `StopwatchesTableViewController` class would look like e.g. this:

```
class StopwatchesTableViewController: UITableViewController, TimerProtocol {
    
    var stopwatch: Stopwatch? = nil
    
    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        stopwatch = Stopwatch(delegate: self)
    }
    
    func timerFired() {
        println("timer");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change,

```
let stopwatch = Stopwatch(delegate: self) // Error here
```

to

```
@lazy var stopwatch: Stopwatch = Stopwatch(delegate: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```swift
let stopwatch = Stopwatch(delegate: self)
```

is in the scope of the class (not inside a `func`) and hence `self` refers to the class (not an instance). The class does not conform to the protocol, only its instances.

You need to do

```swift
let stopwatch: Stopwatch

func init() {
    stopwatch = Stopwatch(delegate: self)
}
```